# Eclipse stopped working with Ubuntu upgrade to 14.04

Tags: java, eclipse

Two days ago I upgraded to the latest Ubuntu 14.04. Everything was working fine, until I tried to open Eclipse that I use for Java development. It shows the loading window but the program never loads. I started Eclipse from command line:

```
eclipse -consolelog
```

I receive the following output:

> !SESSION 2014-04-27 17:57:42.917
>   ----------------------------------------------- eclipse.buildId=debbuild java.version=1.7.0_51 java.vendor=Oracle
>   Corporation BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
>   Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86 -consolelog
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2014-04-27 17:57:49.167 !MESSAGE Unable to
>   create editor ID org.eclipse.jdt.ui.CompilationUnitEditor: No editor
>   descriptor for id org.eclipse.jdt.ui.CompilationUnitEditor !STACK 1
>   org.eclipse.ui.PartInitException: No editor descriptor for id
>   org.eclipse.jdt.ui.CompilationUnitEditor  at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:601)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:465)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorAreaHelper.setVisibleEditor(EditorAreaHelper.java:271)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.setVisibleEditor(EditorManager.java:1459)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager$5.runWithException(EditorManager.java:972)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3537)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3189)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.openWindows(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:803)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$33.runWithException(Workbench.java:1600)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3537)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3189)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2609)     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)   at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)   at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438) !SUBENTRY 1
>   org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2014-04-27 17:57:49.174 !MESSAGE No editor
>   descriptor for id org.eclipse.jdt.ui.CompilationUnitEditor
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 2 2 2014-04-27 17:57:49.416 !MESSAGE Ignored
>   attempt to add saveable that was already registered !STACK 0
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.AssertionFailedException: unknown saveable:
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.DefaultSaveable@13b2f29 from part:
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ErrorEditorPart@13b2f29   at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveablesList.logWarning(SaveablesList.java:187)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveablesList.addModel(SaveablesList.java:116)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveablesList.addModels(SaveablesList.java:289)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveablesList.postOpen(SaveablesList.java:695)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartList.partOpened(PartList.java:234)   at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartList.access$0(PartList.java:210)  at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartList$1.propertyChanged(PartList.java:40)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.fireInternalPropertyChange(WorkbenchPartReference.java:375)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:610)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorAreaHelper.setVisibleEditor(EditorAreaHelper.java:271)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.setVisibleEditor(EditorManager.java:1459)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager$5.runWithException(EditorManager.java:972)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3537)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3189)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.openWindows(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:803)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$33.runWithException(Workbench.java:1600)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3537)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3189)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2609)     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)   at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)   at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2014-04-27 17:57:49.586 !MESSAGE Could not
>   create view: 'org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavadocView'.
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2014-04-27 17:57:49.589 !MESSAGE Could not
>   create view: 'org.eclipse.jdt.ui.SourceView'.
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 2 2 2014-04-27 17:57:49.851 !MESSAGE Perspective
>   Java has been made into a local copy

The past two days I was searching the internet and the farthest I could reach was; deleting the "workspace" folder makes Eclipse starts but without any projects, plugins or settings.

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems,eclipse cannot find its resources. I would suggest re-installing would be best solution. As your workspace is fine, reinstalling it would be easy.

Comment: By the way, did you install eclipse from repository? or downloaded from official eclipse site?

Comment: Eclipse was installed from repository, I resolved the problem by re-installing a newer version of Eclipse from their official website and reconfigured my workspace!

Answer (score 1):

Answer taken from comments

> Eclipse was installed from repository, I resolved the problem by
>   re-installing a newer version of Eclipse from their official website
>   and reconfigured my workspace!

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for your problem is just moving the "~/.eclipse" to another folder.

So:

- Close Eclipse
- Open "Terminal"
- Type the following command:

  ```
   mv ~/.eclipse somewhereYouWant
  ```

  When I got this problem, I just:

  ```
   mv ~/.eclipse home/paladini/Downloads
  ```